# How to efficiently generate combination without repetition with certain distinctive number between them

Tags: c#, algorithm, combinations

How to efficiently generate sets of ***number combination without repetition*** where all sets has certain distinctive number between each other.

***NOTE** : *Range number will always start from 0.*

---

### **Example :**

Range Number **(numbers[ ])** = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7  ==> total 8 numbers **(n)**.

Combination **(k)** = 5 numbers.

Distinctive numbers **(nD)** = 2 numbers.

**Results :**

0 1 2 3 4

0 1 2 5 6

0 1 3 5 7

0 1 4 6 7

0 2 3 6 7

0 2 4 5 7

0 3 4 5 6

***There are 7 valid combinations***

---

### **How it Assembled :**

Since i'm not good with words, so let me visualized them as like this :
[image]

To explain about their distinctive numbers :
[image]

And we could summarize them into this table :
[image]

---

### **What have i achieved so far**

My current solution is very inefficient (or you can call it brute force).

* First i loop for each combination. ==>  **k C n**

* Then i create a temp for valid combination.

* Then for each combination i validate towards my temp, if its valid then  store it in temp, otherwise ignore it.

Thats it.

Here is my code in Console App :

```
class Program
{
    static List<int[]> ValidCombinations;

    static void Main()
    {
        ValidCombinations = new List<int[]>();

        int[] numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 8).ToArray();
        int n = numbers.Length;
        const int k = 5;
        const int nD = 2;

        int maxIntersect = k - nD;

        int iCombination = 0;
        int iValidCombination = 0;
        int[] _temp = new int[k];
        foreach (int[] c in FindCombinations(k, n))
        {
            // #Print out
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                if (c.Contains(i))
                    Console.Write(c[Array.IndexOf(c, i)] + " ");
                else
                    Console.Write("_ ");
            }

            // Save to List
            if (IsValidSet(c, maxIntersect))
            {
                _temp = new int[k];
                for (int i = 0; i < c.Length; i++)
                {
                    _temp[i] = c[i];
                }
                ValidCombinations.Add(_temp);
                iValidCombination++;
                Console.Write(" ### --> {0}", string.Join(" ", c));
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            iCombination++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nTotal Combination = {0}", iCombination);
        Console.WriteLine("Valid Combination Found = {0}", iValidCombination);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<int[]> FindCombosRec(int[] buffer, int done, int begin, int end)
    {
        for (int i = begin; i < end; i++)
        {
            buffer[done] = i;

            if (done == buffer.Length - 1)
                yield return buffer;
            else
                foreach (int[] child in FindCombosRec(buffer, done + 1, i + 1, end))
                    yield return child;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<int[]> FindCombinations(int m, int n)
    {
        return FindCombosRec(new int[m], 0, 0, n);
    }

    private static bool IsValidSet(int[] set, int maxIntersect)
    {
        foreach (var item in ValidCombinations)
        {
            if (set.Intersect(item).Count() > maxIntersect)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

I got the base code to generate the combination from [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations).

---

### **The Issues**

This is work, but for greater range of numbers, this solution will takes a lot of time to complete. I know because the combination algorithm involved , but there must be some kind of shortcut or pattern to simplified it *(which my tiny brain has failed to figure it out)*.

**Thank you very much.**

Comment: A first step towards optimization is fixing the n - k - nD first numbers to be always present (if n - k - nD < 0, then the solution is always made of only one combination). This is your 0 always present in your example.

Comment: My comment above is wrong, let me reformulate it as:
A first step towards optimization would be to determine how many numbers will always be present. In your example 0 is always present; with n = 8, k = 5 and nD = 1, we could fix 0, 1, 2 and 3 to be always present. Also determining the number of lines could surely be useful (7 in your example, 4 in mine). I feel like the number of lines is the number of unfixed numbers but I can't prove it yet.

Comment: @FabianPijcke : Those 3 parameters will always present, i couldn't made any of that number fix, because it would affect the optimum combination it could yield. Maybe i can put it into a real life case like this..

Comment: @FabianPijcke : sorry got clicked while unfinished.. here is the example case : **_"You are a teacher whom about to give an exam to your students, If you have 8 questions and each of your student should get 5 questions, and you want to give 40% differences between your students, then how many students that those combination of questions could cover?"_** ..of course its not about the number, but the combination itself. _(i'm sorry if this case only made more confuse)_.

Comment: No I get the idea, although in your real-life example the professor would not mind if the difference was higher than 40% between some students, that would just be a lower bound IMHO. I was not speaking about one of the parameters but about one of the numbers that is present in all of the subsets (0 never appears in your distinctive number table) ...

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your question, but to me it seems that there is no unique solution: Why would [1 2 3 4 7], [1 2 5 6 7], [0 1 3 5 7], [0 1 4 6 7], [0 2 3 6 7], [0 2 4 5 7], [3 4 5 6 7] be wrong?

Comment: @JonathanvonSchroeder : Your sets isn't wrong, you could start with whatever **5** set of number. The important thing is they should apply the rule _(which is combination of **5** number with **2** distinctive number between each of them)_. Notice that they always yield **7** valid combinations.
The different between our sets is, my sets are _**ordered**_, thats it.

Answer (score 2):

Your matrix representation shows that this problem is homologous or at least very similar to finding a set of different binary words of fixed size, constant [Hamming weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) and with a constant [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) between any pair of them.

**Graphically**:

[image]

As described in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75002), this problem is not necessarily trivial. In particular, the proposed solution explains how to construct the [Hadamard matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HadamardMatrix.html), which rows are the binary words you are looking for.

[image: Image taken from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/HadamardMatrices_800.gif]

This looks very similar to your matrix. Anyway, what you need is a little bit more general. Unlike that case, you don't want every pair of rows to have exactly a distance of `n/2`, but a constant distance of `d < n/2`.

**Bottom line**

The possibility to easily generate sets of binary words with constant size (determined by your `numbers` array's length), constant weight (determined by your `k`) and constant distance (determined by your `nD`) depends heavily on these parameters. Given that [some techniques for generating those sets](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02579148) rely on some assumptions over these parameters, my guess is that there is no efficient algorithm for the general case.

Anyway, it might be useful if you reword your question and ask it on [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net), maybe linking both this question and the one I linked.

**Algorithm suggestion**

As for an algorithm (that, just as yours, won't work with big numbers), you could try the following:

1. Generate a binary word made up of `k` ones followed by `(numbers.Length - nD)` zeroes and store it in a list
2. Iteratively generate every word which has exactly `2*nD` bits different to your original word.
3. For each generated word, try to store it in the list only if it has `2*nD` distance to each other word in the list.

Not so different from your approach, but I think that could work a little bit better, thou.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#define N 8
#define K 5
#define D 2
using namespace std;

vector<vector<int>> vv;
vector<int> v;
int intersection(const vector<int>& a, const vector<int>& b) 
{//count elements of intersection of two sorted vectors
    int count = 0;
    auto a_it = a.begin();
    auto b_it = b.begin();
    while(a_it != a.end() && b_it != b.end()) {
        if(*a_it == *b_it) count++, a_it++, b_it++; 
        else if(*a_it < *b_it) a_it++;
        else b_it++;
    }
    return count;
}

void select_num(int n)
{//might reduce some unnecessary iteration of nCk combination 
    for(auto& a : vv) if(intersection(a, v) > K - D) return;
    //above line will cut off the chain when the intersection is already over 
    //limit. You can add some more conditions to cut off unnecessary calculation.
    if(v.size() == K) {
        bool ok = true;
        for(auto& a : vv) {
            if(intersection(a, v) != K - D) {
                ok = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(ok) vv.push_back(v);
        return;
    }
    if(n == N) return;

    //case : select n
    v.push_back(n);
    select_num(n+1);
    v.pop_back();

    //case : do not select n
    select_num(n+1);
}

int main()
{
    select_num(0);
    for(auto& a : vv) {
        for(auto& b : a) cout << b << ' ';
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << vv.size() << endl;
}
```